# How to create object within function MatLab without creating a new file

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I am working on a project with the following specs:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xaCK-1Mpd8FXM-19pfFC1UTk2V9oXkQ/view?usp=sharing

My code is attached below.
How do I get my final output as a data object and info object like they are asking, without creating a new class file? The format required is in the picture below.

Final format required:

[image: format]

```
function [data,info] = OneNormLPxxx(A,b)
%L1 norm minimization for a given A and b.
%   Detailed explanation goes here
count = 0;
b_vect = b;
[m,n] = size(A);
max_count = 3*nchoosek(m,n);
set_B = 1:n;
M = inv(A(set_B, :));
is_opt = 0;
while (is_opt == 0)
    if (det(A(set_B,:)) == 0)
        info = untitled4;
        info.run = "Failure";
        info.msg = "Degeneracy Problem";
        data = untitled3;
        return
    end
    if (max_count <= count)
        info = untitled4;
        info.run = "Failure";
        info.msg = "Arithmetic Problem";
        data = untitled3;
        return
    end
    set_B_Comp = setdiff(1:m,set_B);
    x_temp = M*b_vect(set_B);
    h = A*x_temp - b_vect;
    h(set_B_Comp) = A(set_B_Comp,:)*x_temp - b_vect(set_B_Comp);
    y_vect = zeros(m, 1);
    y_vect(set_B_Comp) = sign(h(set_B_Comp));
    y_vect(set_B) = -(M')*((A(set_B_Comp,:)')*y_vect(set_B_Comp));
    abs_y_B = abs(y_vect(set_B));
    if all(abs_y_B <=  1)
        is_opt = 1;
        x_opt = x_temp;
        opt_val = sum(abs(A*x_opt - b_vect));
        data = untitled3;
        data.obj = opt_val;
        data.x = x_opt;
        data.loop = count;
        info = untitled4;
        info.run = "Success";
        return
        % return B and x
    else
        all_index_y_vect_more_than_1 = find(abs(y_vect(set_B)) > 1);
        s = all_index_y_vect_more_than_1(1);
        y_s = y_vect(s);
        t_vect = zeros(m, 1);
        t_vect(set_B_Comp) = -(sign(y_s))*(y_vect(set_B_Comp)).*(A(set_B_Comp,:)*M(:,s));
        cur_min = abs(h(set_B_Comp(1)))/t_vect(set_B_Comp(1)) + 1;
        cur_r = set_B_Comp(1);
        for j = set_B_Comp
            h_j = h(j);
            t_j = t_vect(j);
            temp1 = abs(h_j)/t_j;
            if (temp1 < cur_min) && (temp1 > 0) && (t_j > 0)
                cur_min = temp1;
                cur_r = j;
            end
        end
        r = cur_r;
        j_s = set_B(s);
        set_B_new = setdiff(union(set_B, r), j_s);
        set_B = set_B_new;
        set_B_Comp = setdiff(1:m,set_B);
        theta = (A(r,:)*M)';
        M(:,s) = (1/theta(s))*M(:,s);
        for j = 1:n
            if (j ~= s)
                M(:,j) = M(:,j) - theta(j)*M(:,s);
            end
        end
    end
    count = count + 1;
end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear what the problem is here. You've defined yout function to have two outputs; a structure called `data` and one called `info`. Call your function accordingly (from the command line, another function or script) and it'll work. Could you please [edit] your post to clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Those are not objects of a custom class, they are structs. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using

```
info = untitled4;
```

Use

```
info = struct();
```

This will create a MATLAB structure for storing your data.